# Types of Wildcards in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

My query:

```
Select * From tableName Where columnName Like "[PST]%"
```

is not giving the expected result.

Why does this wildcard not work in MySql?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to use a wildcard on the table name itself?

Comment: It looks like you're using the `LIKE` [syntax supported by Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Their implementation has enhanced wildcards, but they are not standard SQL, and other products like MySQL don't support them.

Comment: @GMB I want to fetch out row starting with P or S or T from Column: "columnName"

Comment: @Filburt No, btw correct me if I am wrong wildcards can only be apply on Column to fetch out rows. Am I write ?

Comment: @BillKarwin Oh thanks, so can you suggest some alternative to do so ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks everyone!

For specific this question, we need to use regexp

Select * From tableName Where ColumnName Regexp "^[PST]";

For more detail over Regular Expression i.e Regexp :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoltE-JUY0c

Comment: Please remember to upvote those answers which you found helpful, and accept the most relevant answer to your question.

Comment: External resources, especially videos, don't provide the answer directly.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to filter on strings that contain any `'P'`, `'S'`, or `'T'`, then you can use a regex:

```
where col rlike '[PST]'
```

If you want strings that contain substring `'PST'`, then no need for square brackets - and `like` is enough:

```
where col like '%PST%'
```

If you  want the matching character(s) at the start of the string, then the regex solution looks like:

```
where col rlike '^PST'
```

And the `like` option would be:

```
where col like 'PST%'
```

Comment: Would give 10 upvotes if I could for `rlike`.  What have I been missing?!  Learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: @S3DEV I think, I going to got 10 upvotes because I have the detail regarding rlike/regexp

Answer (score 5):

MySQL's LIKE syntax is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Standard SQL from decades ago defined only two wildcards: `%` and `_`. These are the only wildcards an SQL product needs to support if they want to say they are SQL compliant and support the `LIKE` predicate.

`%` matches zero or more of any characters. It's analogous to `.*` in regular expressions.

`_` matches exactly one of any character. It's analogous to `.` in regular expressions.

Also if you want to match a literal '%' or '_', you need to escape it, i.e. put a backslash before it:

```
WHERE title LIKE 'The 7\% Solution'
```

Microsoft SQL Server's LIKE syntax is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

They support `%` and `_` wildcards, and the `\` escape character, but they extend standard SQL with two other forms:

`[a-z]` matches one character, but only characters in the range inside the brackets. This is similar in regular expressions. The `-` is a range operator, unless it appears at the start or end of the string inside the brackets.

`[^a-z]` matches one character, which must *not* be one of the characters in the range inside the brackets. Also the same in regular expressions.

These are not standard forms of wildcards for the `LIKE` predicate, and other brands of SQL database don't support them.

Later versions of the SQL standard introduced a new predicate `SIMILAR TO` which supports much richer patterns and wildcards, since the right-side operand is a string which contains a regular expression. But since this predicate was introduced in a later edition of the SQL standard, some implementations had already developed their own solution that was almost the same.

MySQL called the operator `REGEXP` and `RLIKE` is a synonym (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).

It was requested in https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=746 to support `SIMILAR TO` syntax to help MySQL comply with the SQL standard, but the request was turned down, because it had subtly different behavior to the existing `REGEXP`/`RLIKE` operator.

Microsoft SQL Server has partial support of regular expression wildcards in the `LIKE` operator, and also a `dbo.RegexMatch()` function.

SQLite has a `GLOB` operator, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your details explanation with other relevant details.